# Mysql TIME confusion

Tags: mysql, time, display

Created a table with some columns of type `TIME(3)` Loaded from a CSV file

```
0:07.763
0:07.783
0:07.276
0:07.484
0:07.127
```

Running `select * from some_table` yields the following:

```
00:00:07.763
00:00:07.783
00:00:07.276
00:00:07.484
00:00:07.127
```

My question is: How can I get this to display in a select statement without the leading 0's ? Something like:

```
7.763
7.783
7.276
7.484
7.127
```

tried various permutations of `TRIM` but those all failed.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that in your query? Why not in your rendering code?

Comment: `SELECT .. , SUBSTRING_INDEX(time_column, ':', -1) + 0 , ..`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TIME_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) function to format your times in your query.

Something like this should work:

```
select ROUND(TIME_FORMAT(time1, '%s.%f'), 3) from some_table
```

The `%s` part is the seconds and the `%f` part is the microseconds.

Comment: Thanks. But that only changes the problem to: 07.763000

Comment: @Quark Try rounding - `ROUND(TIME_FORMAT(time1, '%s.%f'), 3)`

Comment: If you want to use time functions then better use time_to_sec()

Answer (score 1):

Exactly for this purpose the function [`TIME_TO_SEC()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) exists:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(time1) FROM some_table
```

This is much faster, since the function does a simple mathematical operation (tm.hour * 3600 + tm.minute * 60 + tm.second + tm.microsecond / 1000000) instead of parsing a string before:

```
select benchmark(10000000, time_to_sec("00:00:07.363"));
0.097 sec

select benchmark(10000000, round(time_format("00:00:07.363", "%s.%f"),3))
2.215 sec
```

But many roads lead to Rome:...

```
SELECT time1 + 0 FROM some_table

SELECT CAST(time1 AS DECIMAL(4,3)) FROM some_table

SELECT SECOND(time1) + MICROSECONDS(time1) / 1000000 FROM some_table

SELECT ROUND(TIME_FORMAT(time1, '%s.%f'), 3) FROM some_table

SELECT ROUND(RIGHT(time1,6),3) FROM some_table
...
```

Comment: Alas, it appears that some do not ;-) - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WiOYp6S7)

Comment: Please measure that on a standalone machine, not on a shared server. Preferrable on a unix_socket connection to reduce network overhead.

Comment: It wasn't a reference to the speed, but instead the variants that do not work as OP requires. I ran them on a standalone server (Oracle Linux 9.2/MySQL 8.0.34 on bare metal) and got similar ratios on perf.